# jQuery and margin: 0 auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, this is a problem that's been asked before, but I'm hoping we can lay it to rest: I'm using jQuery 1.4. If I define the style

```
#obj { margin: 0 auto; }
```

and then do

```
$('#obj').css('marginLeft');
```

the result is the computed value in pixels. Is there any way to tell whether those pixels come from the `auto` calculation or not, without parsing `document.styleSheets`?

Comment: From what I've just researched, I don't think you'll be able to access original styles from jQuery, only the computed styles, unless you parse the stylesheets themselves. What is the particular reason for wanting to do this anyway?

Comment: Do you mean to check if jQuery modified the `margin-left` property from its original value of `auto`? Or do you mean to check whether or not the original stylesheet property was set to `auto`?

Comment: Given that *at best* it's going to be a huge pain to get the styles, you may want to describe what your overall goal is here. Somebody might have an alternative approach that's more likely to work.

Comment: OK, here's a simple scenario: I want to resize an element. If its margins have been set to `auto`, then I want to keep it centered; and if its margins have been set in pixels or other units, then I want to respect those instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution would also be triggered if the margins were set to percentages, but it might be good enough for your purposes.  Basically, you record which margins change on resize.  So you'd record the margins before resize to an array:

```
var aMargins = [];
$('.yourObjs').each(function(i,obj){
  var objML = $(obj).css('marginLeft');
  aMargins.push(objML);
});
```

Then resize the window, see which margins changed (these will be either 'auto' or %), do what you need to do to them and return he window to original size:

```
var wW = $(window).width();
var wH = $(window).height();  
window.resizeTo(wW - 5, wH);
$('.yourObjs').each(function(i,obj){
  if ($(obj).css('marginLeft') != aMargins[i]) {
    // your centering code here
  }
}
window.resizeTo(wW,wH);
```

If your centering code just adjusts the left margin then this should work fine for % based margins too.  I can't test this code or provide an example because I'm on the road and writing from my phone, but hopefully this works or helps you come up with something that will.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the `auto` from the element itself, because styles are cascading, what if you had this?

```
#obj { margin: 0 auto; }
div #obj { margin: 0 10px; }
```

Which is it? Depends on the page and how it cascades, the basic concept is you're getting the **calculated** style properties *on that element*, what's in the stylesheet doesn't matter, there could be 20 stylesheets, etc.

Basically it boils down to this: getting `auto` vs `000px` is a *really* rare request and would required a *lot* of extra code to figure out, so much so that it's an easy case of "no, this doesn't belong in core".  However, **[there are plugins to do CSS parsing](http://bililite.com/blog/2009/01/16/jquery-css-parser/)**.

Short answer: jQuery core *cannot* (doesn't have code to) do this, jQuery with plugins, or just JavaScript in general *yes* you can.

Comment: Yes, I realize that jQuery core can't do this. It's not obvious how the plugin you linked to will help me to do this, either. In the case you give, surely someone has written code that will tell me whether the `auto` style is active on `#obj`?

Comment: @Trevor - You're trying to access which style in the stylesheet for a particular CSS property is assigned to that element...but that's not something that's exposed by the browser, it was never part of any spec and there isn't a property you can access it through.  Remember though JavaScript is a dynamic language, properties it accesses are available on the DOM somewhere, **explicitly** exposed by native code...this one isn't :)  In most cases "auto" is actually transformed into a centering function hooked to a flow change event handler, after it's attached, it doesn't care if it said "auto" :)

Comment: I get that it's not directly exposed, but it can, in principle, be discovered. For instance, if the container element were resized, then the computed margins would change. So I'm asking: How to discover it? Is there a jQuery plugin that can take care of that discovery for me?

Comment: @Trevor - I don't think I'm conveying it correctly, it's *not* exposed **to JavaScript** *at all*, directly or not, there is no way to get this from the browser...all you can do is traverse the cascading style tree (by parsing your CSS in your own code) and attempt to see which rule matches it.  jQuery can't find what JavaScript as a whole can't see.  The margins are changing on resize yes, but the browser's doing it, and it's not exposing it's thought process or variables used along the way.  *How* it works doesn't matter...it's the API *you can see* that matters, and you can't see this.