# jQuery and the accuracy of the css function

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery and margin: 0 auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029178/jquery-and-margin-0-auto)

I have the following HTML:

```
<p style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:200px;">Hello</p>
```

I then use jQuery to get `margin-left` like so:

```
alert(window.jQuery(element).css('margin-left'));
```

However, it alerts `0px` rather than the expected `auto`.

Why is this the case and how can I get the auto?

Comment: I'm just checking out http://sizzlejs.com - it is a CSS parser. Might be a bit extreme for this question.

Comment: Sizzle won't help you for two reasons: 1) It's just a selector engine: it selects elements based on a CSS selector. It does not grab values for CSS properties of an element. 2) You are already using Sizzle because it's the selector engine used in jQuery :)

Comment: @maxedison - I realized this as soon as I tried to get the demo to work! :) Having a look at http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/ - but this getting a bit much for one small issue.

Comment: It looks like if I attempt the above in IE9 it works the way I want it to work but in FF and Chrome it returns a `auto` as `0px` - seems IE is right for once.

Comment: It is also strange that mootools can show the `auto`.

Comment: Two different things.  `auto` is the **markup** in your CSS.  `.css('margin-left')` is the **actual** size of the margin in the DOM.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean since using the actual size inline instead of auto does not move the p tag to the centre.

Comment: Use `@` in front of the username or they won't be notified.  @Abs, `auto` is not a "measurement" of anything, it's a "setting".  `auto` is your markup which means the _actual_ size of the left margin will be variable depending on other elements, window size, etc.  `.css('margin-left')` gives you the *actual* measurement of that margin at that one time.  In your case, it returned `0px` because the `<p>` was not moved towards center.  `margin:auto` only works with respect to the element's container... apparently, your container was not wide enough or in the correct position for `auto` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution! This little function will take a jQuery selector, scan all your stylesheets, filter the rules that affects the given DOM elements, parse these rules and return an object with a list of CSS rules resulted from the interaction of all inheritances involved.

```
<style type="text/css">

    .fool{
        margin-left:200px;
    }

    #fool{
        margin-left:auto;
    }
</style>

<div id="fool" class="fool" style="font-size:100px; height:20px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('document').ready(function($){

        function get_inheritance_result(jQueryElement){
            var styleSheets = document.styleSheets, finalRules = {};
            for(var i in styleSheets) {
                var rules = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
                for(var r in rules) {
                var selector = String(rules[r].selectorText);
                    if(selector.indexOf(':') == -1){ //ignoring pseudo selectors, they will not matter here
                        if(jQueryElement.is(selector.toString())) {
                            console.log(selector.toString()); // Will log all the selectors that are affecting the particular DOM element
                            finalRules = $.extend(finalRules, rules[r].style);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //taking any inline css and overriding it on top of our finalRules variable:
            var inlineCSS = jQueryElement.prop('style');
            for(i in inlineCSS){
                if(inlineCSS.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                    if(inlineCSS[i] != ""){
                        finalRules[i] = inlineCSS[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            //and voila!
            return finalRules;
        }

        var style = get_inheritance_result($("#fool"));
        console.log(style); //logs all the resulted css rules
        alert(style.marginLeft); // 'auto'!
        alert(style.fontSize); // '100px'!
    });
</script>
```

**Thanks for asking that question, learned a lot trying to solve that problem.**

Comment: Wow, awesome! :) Is there a way to combine the inline styles with any other CSS whether external or in style blocks into the above function whilst maintaining computed priority?

Comment: the css from style blocks are already being processed... just the CSS declared inside style property is being ignored... I'm trying to combine it now, let's see.

Comment: Edited the answer. I think the solution is complete now. The CSS declared inside style property is now being processed too and is overriding the stylesheet inheritances! o/ finally a before-computing CSS property access. (I'm thinking in writing a jQuery plugin now, but later... got hungry) lol

Comment: lol awesome work man! I tried it but I think I am not using function correctly as I keep getting undefined with this: `var style = get_inheritance_result($('#pod')); alert(style.height);`. I have a `p` tag with an id of `pod` - I've also wrapped the functional call in document ready.

Comment: $('#pod') might be empty. Try `alert($('#pod')[0]);`. Is there really any element in your DOM with a `#pod` id? (it's necessary because were working with DOM elements, not with CSS alone).

Comment: Yes that element exists. When I echo it I get `[object Object]`. This is the p tag: `<p id="pod" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:200px; background-color: yellow;">Hello</p>`. The weird thing is when I echo `style` it too shows its not empty.

Comment: You can try my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/tLULp/

Comment: Well, height being undefined is completely normal in your case since height was not assigned anywhere in your css. Now I got confused of what exactly you want to do. What did you expected to be alerted?

Comment: The example shows width? The above is a typo. See example.

Comment: Well, what happens here is the following (in your JSFiddle) I see 3 alerts, first two are showing [object Object] and the last shows '200px'. Running in Opera 11.51

Comment: Yes in Opera it works and in IE9. But not in Firefox, this was the problem I was experiencing. See the 5th comment to the question.

Comment: It seems Chrome and Firefox have a wrong implementation of the CSSStyleDeclaration (they do not inherit all the properties they should, so these properties become unavailableand and accessing it later return undefined values). I noticed the only property all browsers have in common for the CSSStyleDeclaration is the `cssText`, it can be used to achieve a cross browser solution.

Comment: Ah I see that explains a lot! Thank you for telling me that info! Is opera the most standards compliant browser? Is there a browser or league table for this sort of thing?

Comment: It's quite difficult to affirm that a given browser is the most Javascript standard compliance since development cycles are getting shorter and with every new version things can change a bit, but latest Opera beta was quite ahead in terms of javascript (even ahead of chrome).